# Can I interrupt the loop through a command completion custom list to trigger recomputation of the list?

Tags: autocompletion, command

Here's a minimal example:

```
function s:compl_list(argLead, cmdLine, cursorPos)
  if a:argLead == 'opts='
    return map(['op1', 'op2', 'op3'], {_, v -> a:argLead . v })
  endif
  return ['initial', 'list', 'with', 'opts=']
endfunction
fun s:compl(argLead, cmdLine, cursorPos)
  echom join(s:compl_list(a:argLead, a:cmdLine, a:cursorPos), "\n")
  return join(s:compl_list(a:argLead, a:cmdLine, a:cursorPos), "\n")
endf
command! -nargs=* -complete=custom,s:compl Foo echo <args>
```

With this in place, if I write `:Foo`, <kbd>Space</kbd>, and then <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get `:Foo opts=` on the command line. Now, if I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> again, I'm back to `:Foo` , and the loop through `['initial', 'list', 'with', 'opts=']` restarts.

To get the completion after `opts=` work, I need to interrupt the current looping somehow, e.g. via <kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>, so that the following <kbd>Tab</kbd>s will loop through `['op1', 'op2', 'op3']`.

This is a bit clunky.

I understand that having <kbd>Tab</kbd> loop through `['op1', 'op2', 'op3']` right after I reached `:Foo opts=` via <kbd>Tab</kbd> is probably impossible (how would <kbd>Tab</kbd> know that I want to restart the completion rather than looping back?), but I was wondering if there is a way to break the loop with one key combination. (A bit like <kbd>Ctrl+Y</kbd>, [`complete_CTRL-Y`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#complete_CTRL-Y), to dismiss the pum.)